# Routing with Two Subnets - Azure VPN to RRAS (inside WRT1900AC Network)

Tags: vpn, routing, router, azure, linksys

In my network I have a Linksys WRT1900AC Router and a Microsoft RRAS VPN Server.  The local LAN address is 10.10.1.0/24.

In Azure, I have a Network that has a VPN connection to my RRAS VPN Server inside my network, but I am forced to use a different subnet with Azure in order to add a required gateway.

I am looking to find out how to allow my local network access that of the Azure Cloud network hopefully with routing from the WRT1900AC Linksys Router, or from the computers inside the network using NET ADD.  (I seem to be unable to do that too.)

In Azure, the VPN shows connected, in RRAS it shows connected as well. So there is a VPN connection for sure.

Here is a screenshot of my network setup from Azure.[image]

Here is a screen shot of my network in the Linksys Router:
[image]

Next, here is a screenshot of the routing in the Linksys, hopefully this configuration layout makes sense, and someone could advise what I may be able to put in here.[image]

And finally, here is a screen shot of what I am trying to do with that route, but it doesn't seem to be adding...
[image]

Comment: What is your RRAS server ip? In the static routing entry, try adding your RRAS server ip at the Gateway field, (if I have understood it correctly). May be you will also need a route at your Azure, for your local net.

Comment: Okay, I added the RRAS in there, its 10.10.1.10.

Comment: But what should my route add command look like on the RRAS server?

Comment: First check, if you can reach 10.10.3.8 from your local net.

Comment: I can't, in fact, I can't even access it from the RRAS

Comment: I think you are missing the necessary routing at your RRAS server. That is important. Look at "Scenario Two" here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178993